# Why did my function stop working with no changes?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Trying to learn Python, so excuse the poorly written code. I had the SetIcon() function working to set a Pixmap above the temperature and literally nothing changed, I only didn't work on it for a few days and now it isn't setting the Pixmap at all. Prior to this it worked perfectly. Everything else works fine and when I create new Pixmaps with the same icons, they appear.

Created other functions to make sure the link to the icons weren't broken. 
Re-wrote the function. I also created a Try Except, but there were no errors thrown. It's almost like the function isn't running, but I know it is because I can make it print to the console. The function has just stopped attaching a Pixmap to the label.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 240, 320)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: black")

        flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)

        self.coolIcon = QtGui.QPixmap("cool.png")
        self.heatIcon = QtGui.QPixmap("heat.png")
        self.fanIcon = QtGui.QPixmap("fan.png")
        self.powerIcon = QtGui.QPixmap("power.png")
        self.currentOperationLbl = QLabel()
        self.currentTempLbl = QLabel(self)
        self.homeIcon = QtGui.QPixmap("home.png")
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)

        self.SetIcon()
        self.CurrentTemp()

        self.show()


    def CurrentTemp(self):

        currentTemp = 67

        self.currentTempLbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Gotham", 27, weight=QtGui.QFont.Light))
        self.currentTempLbl.setGeometry(70, 100, 100, 100)
        self.currentTempLbl.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffff;")
        self.currentTempLbl.setText(str(currentTemp))


    def SetIcon(self):

        status = 4

        self.currentOperationLbl.setGeometry(30, 80, 30, 30)

        if status == 1:
            self.currentOperationLbl.setPixmap(self.heatIcon)

        elif status == 2:
            self.currentOperationLbl.setPixmap(self.coolIcon)

        elif status == 3:
            self.currentOperationLbl.setPixmap(self.fanIcon)

        elif status == 4:
            self.currentOperationLbl.setText("System Off")
            self.currentOperationLbl.setGeometry(92, 70, 50, 30)
            self.currentOperationLbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Gotham", 3, weight=QtGui.QFont.Light))
            self.currentOperationLbl.setStyleSheet("color: #ffffff;")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the problem is? What did it do before that it no longer does?

Comment: Hoog: It would set an Icon above the temperature based on what int was in Status. I will update the question.

Comment: change `self.currentOperationLbl = QLabel()` to `self.currentOperationLbl = QLabel(self)`

Comment: S. Nick: THANK YOU! That was driving me crazy and I couldn't see where the disconnect was.